# How to get the name of sub class from parent class in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can i get the name of the sub class (which is invoking the constructor of base class) from base class itself in `TypeScript` . I have code setup as:

```
class Animal{
    constructor(){ console.log(this.constructor.name)} //this is throwing error}
}
class Cow extends Animal{
 constructor(){ super() }
}
new Cow() // this should log "Cow"
```

In plane `Js` `this.constructor.name` used to work but seems like this is not the case in `TypeScript`.
The error I'm getting is :

```
 error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Function'.
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: [works for me](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Animal%7B%20constructor()%20%7B%20console.log(%22name%22%2C%20this.constructor.name)%3B%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Cow%20extends%20Animal%7B%20constructor()%7B%20super()%20%7D%20%7D%0D%0Anew%20Cow()), after I've removed that inline comment, that "hides" the closing `}` of *Animal#constructor()*, and added some actual logging

Comment: hmm ! how come it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Is this error a compilation error or runtime error? If it's a compilation error, then what typescript version are you running?

Comment: @ Nitzan Tomer yes this is compilation error and the version i'm using is 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

The only reason this should fail is in Internet Explorer / IE Mobile, as the `Function.name` basic support is not present. In all other browsers, it should work.

This even works if you target `ESNEXT` and the output contains ECMAScript classes (i.e. like the TypeScript does). The below code will work in your fast-paced happy browsers... and if you run it through the TypeScript compiler, the plain version works too (except as stated above).

```js
class Animal {
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.constructor.name);
    }
}

class Cow extends Animal{
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

new Cow();
```

Comment: this code is same as my question . this is not working!!! Thats why i asked for help..

Comment: @CodeBloded - what browser are you using? I have tested on multiple browsers and noted those that don't work on my answer.

Comment: i am using chrome